# iframe funciona en Xampp y no en el host

Tags: php, xampp, iframe

Estoy haciendo una pequeña aplicación en php/html.

En mi index.php defino un par de iframes.

La he programado y probado con Xampp y funciona correctamente. Ahora la subo a mi host y el iframe "iframe_ppal" no carga su contenido.

El código de index.php es el siguiente:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>STP Index</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Themes/BlueNote/Style.css">

</head>
<body bgcolor="#FFFFF7" text="#000000" link="#000000" vlink="#000000" alink="#FF0000" class="CobaltPageBODY">
<p>
<table bordercolor="#330099" cellspacing="0" bordercolordark="#330099" cellpadding="1" width="50%" bordercolorlight="#330099" border="3">
  <tr valign="top" align="left">
    <td><iframe src="menu.html" height="400" width="290" style="border:none;" name="iframe_menu"></iframe></td> 
    <td><iframe src="login.php" height="400" width="800" style="border:none;" name="iframe_ppal"></iframe></td> 

  </tr>
</table>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Agradezco por adelantado el apoyo que puedan darme.

Comment: Puedes probar a llamar los archivos dentro de tu iframe con la ruta absoluta en lugar de una relativa. Algo así como `<iframe src="https://midominio.com/menu.html" height="400" width="290" style="border:none;" name="iframe_menu"></iframe>`

Answer (score 1):

existe una una característica de seguridad en los navegadores que impide acceder a ciertos objetos DOM dentro de iFrames.

por ejemplo: Si estás intentando realizar algún scrapping o algún proceso de automatización web a través de un iFrame, no funciona. tambien, no deberia funcionar un script php ejecutado en iframe que permita el acceso desde otro lugar.

Comment: creo que por ahí va mi problema.Intenté cargar mi página login.php sola, directamente, y tampoco carga. Es decir que hay un problema que me parece es de seguridad en ese archivo. ¿Es posible que te ponga aquí ese archivo y me ayudes a ver qué está mal?, por los momentos he cambiado mi conexión a base de datos por msqli, y estoy tratando de usar un módulo de sesiones seguras para el manejo de sesiones, pero sigue sin aparecer nada, y no tengo idea cómo hacer.

Comment: @en la pregunta inicial mencionas que si funciona sola, si quieres hacer otra pregunta, debes generar otra pregunta comentando tu problema.

Comment: ya la generé, gracias

Answer (score 0):

Muchas gracias por su ayuda. Hice pruebas y el problema es que la página entra con htpps y mi login parece tener un problema de seguridad (el login es la página que debía aparecer en el iframe).
De hecho cuando trato de cargar directamente la página del login no aparece y me poner el mensaje "no es segura". Voy a abrir una nueva consulta para ver qué estoy haciendo mal en ese aspecto porque estuve investigando y no veo cual es el problema.

Gracias por sus respuestas.

Comment: soy algo novata en el uso de esto, debí agregar esto como comentario de una de las respuestas. Gracias por la observación.